# Facebook Style Message Popup?

Tags: facebook, popup, message

My site has a `Send Message` button next to the link to a users profile. When the user clicks on it (using the `onClick` handler) I want to open a Facebook-style message window, instead of a new window (`window.open()` method).

It doesn't have to be exactly the same as Facebook's, but I want a similar kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Jquery-UI. they have a lot of popuppable windows. Probably want to couple that with some Ajax, and bam, dynamic message popups.